# PySide/pyQt displaying data in QTableView

Tags: pyqt4, pyside, qtableview

I want to add data (read from a file) to the QTableView, but looking over the functions at http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTableView.html#qtableview,
there doesn't seem to be anything that does that.

I've been lead to believe that I should be using TableView instead of tabelWidget for custom data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for using a `QTableView` is that rather than adding data to the view directly, you can use the Model-View-Controller paradigm instead.

You need to [**create a subclass**](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html#subclassing) of [QAbstractItemModel](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html#PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel), and then set the model using [`QAbstractItemView.setModel()`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractItemView.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractItemView.setModel), which `QTableView` inherits from.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look in to that.